# What is the GWT equivalent of setTimeout?

Tags: gwt

I wanted to know the GWT equivalent of `setTimeout` function available in JavaScript?

I Searched for this but was not able to find any information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Timer.schedule](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html#schedule-int-)

> Schedules a timer to elapse in the future.

eg.:

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
  public void run() {
    Window.alert("Nifty, eh?");
  }
};

// Schedule the timer to run once in 5 seconds.
t.schedule(5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the methods of the [Scheduler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html) class.  They allow you to schedule commands on a fixed periodicity (once every *n* milliseconds), fixed delay (wait *n* milliseconds after completing command), or just one-time deferred commands.

The methods of this class provide an advantage over [Timer.schedule](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer.html), as they provide more flexibility as to when your command will be invoked, and require you to code less yourself.

Comment: ...but a timer can be canceled or rescheduled, not a ScheduledCommand.

Answer (score 3):

To remove boilerplate code, I made this method (requires GWT 2.8 or above):

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Command;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler;

public static void delay(int delayMs, Command afterDelay) {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(
        () -> {
            afterDelay.execute();
            return false;
        },
        delayMs);
}
```

So you can now just do this (eg: delay for 2 seconds, and then call myMethod):

```
delay(2000, () -> myMethod());
```

Easy.  :-)